# What is it called when an update only modifies for new data?

Tags: java, coding-style, terminology

I am trying to name a method which will only perform an update on a relational data store if the input data is *new*, meaning there is no existing key or the value differs from the previous. The motivation, is to not trigger a data change event which gets thrown by a standard update.

What is the correct terminology for such an update and what would an example signature be?

Comment: Currently, I am just suffixing the method name with *IfStateChanged*. I'm not sure if there is better terminology to describe this, since IfStateChanged is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard terminology for this.  Personally, I'd just use the normal name, and state in the Javadoc that no actual database update is made if the update would not result in changing any data.

Comment: In SQL, `update` can only update already-existing rows while `insert` will only insert new rows (and fail if a row for given key already exists), so maybe that's a convention you could use.

Comment: @WarrenDew there already is an update call existing, so it is a confusing API to make the client decide on this or the new call based on the java docs.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski In my case though, I only want an update to execute, if the state of the data has changed.

Comment: @stevebot In that case I would append "IfChanged" - though I'd consider replacing the existing call, unless there's some reason that you'd want to update a row with the same data the row already has in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's clarify your statement "only perform an update ... if the input data is new".

If you only focus on relational *keys*, updating only when *keys* change, then you don't really "only perform ... if ... new", as the values for the key might have changed.

However, if you really might have the exact same value applied twice, and you do nothing the second time, the system is **idempotent**.  **Idempotent** apis assure a state after they are called, which will not alter in a replay situation.

A quick example of a non-idempotent call (due to API design)

```
incrementCount();
```

while an example of an idempotent call (with an API permitting it)

```
setCount(5);
```

Note that not doing anything isn't a feature of the *idempotent api*, but rather an optimization which is safe to perform for idempotent calls.  Basically, with an idempotent api, you can do the following

```
if (currentCommand.equals(lastCommand)) {
  return;
}
```